# Can anyone explain rolling Updates in Linux Distribution?

Tags: linux

I'm new to the "Rolling Update" term, but I need to get a brief idea about What is this Rolling Updates?, I searched in the internet for get some resources about this, but did not get anything which is describing term "Rolling Update" properly. 
So can anyone help me?

Comment: Server Fault is not a resource for looking up terminology or definitions.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, SF is not a great place to do primary research.  Secondly, there isn't any general agreement on how most terms of art are used; if there were, that would imply the existence of some central dictionary or authority, and you'd just go and look it up there.  So it helps to point us to the usage of the term that you want clarified (ie, "*how are RedHat using the term `rolling update` in this document*", giving both a link and the relevant excerpt.

That said, I understand *rolling updates* to mean getting updates continuously, as they are released, rather than waiting for a whole chunk of them to arrive in eg a service pack or OS point release.  In the limiting case, a distro, package or OS can abandon the idea of chunked release altogether, and say "you take our fixes in a continuous dribble, or not at all".

The benefits of the chunked approach are that the updates are all (supposedly) regression-tested against each other, to make sure they apply cleanly and don't stand on each other's feet.

The benefits of the dribbled approach are that you get protection against the vulnerabilities or bugs fixed by each patch as it is released.  You have to judge whether your primary concern is security or stability, and apply accordingly.